# make/merge multiple functions into one (or at least fewer) in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have 18 buttons that I can click and I have the same function (clicking it changes the image) for each button and I would like to just use 1 function instead of 18. Moreover, each function also has another function attached that prints the number and the class of the button into an input field. If someone could help me slim all this code down into just a few or even 1 function would be awesome. Only pure html and javascript please.

This is the first 2 double functions of my javascript code:

```
function changeColor1() {
    if (document.getElementById("seatButton1").className == "seatLargeGreen") {
        document.getElementById("seatButton1").className = "seatLargeBlue";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("seatButton1").className == "seatLargeBlue") {
        document.getElementById("seatButton1").className = "seatLargeGreen";
    }
}
seatButton1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    changeColor1();  
});
function num1() {
    if (document.getElementById('seatButton1').className === "seatLargeBlue") {
        document.getElementById('snum').value = 1;
        document.getElementById('sclass').value = "Business";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('snum').value = "";
        document.getElementById('sclass').value = ""
    }
}
seatButton1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    num1();
});
function changeColor2() {
    if (document.getElementById("seatButton2").className == "seatLargeGreen") {
        document.getElementById("seatButton2").className = "seatLargeBlue";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("seatButton2").className == "seatLargeBlue") {
        document.getElementById("seatButton2").className = "seatLargeGreen";
    }
}
seatButton2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    changeColor2();  
});
function num2() {
    if (document.getElementById('seatButton2').className === "seatLargeBlue") {
        document.getElementById('snum').value = 2;
        document.getElementById('sclass').value = "Business";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('snum').value = "";
        document.getElementById('sclass').value = ""
    }
}
seatButton2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    num2();
});
```

There are 16 more like this. Here is the html for this part:

```
<article class="column1">
   <table class="table_seats">
      <tr>
         <td id="seatButton1" class="seatLargeGreen" colspan="2">
            <button class="seat_button_large">
               1
            </button>
         </td>
         <td class="aisle" rowspan="3"></td>
         <td id="seatButton2" class="seatLargeGreen" colspan="2">
            <button class="seat_button_large">
               2
            </button>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</article>
```

I don't think the css is necessary.

I've tried using `document.querySelectorAll("#seatButton1, #seatButton2, ...")` instead of `document.getElementById()` but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: You can select all the buttons by class with `document.getElementsByClassName()` and iterate through them with a `for` loop.

Comment: how would I implement that with my code? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more efficient way to do this would be to attach relevant data (snum, sclass) to the seat elements via data attributes and pass the element to the handler. Then your one event handler will read the data from the clicked element and update appropriately. Also, perform your doc queries **once** and store the results in  variables.

```js
const sclass = document.getElementById('sclass')
const snum = document.getElementById('snum')
const seats = document.querySelectorAll('td[class^="seat"]') // class attribute starts with...

function select(seat) {
  if (seat.className == "seatLargeGreen") {
    // find the previously selected seat
    let active = document.querySelector('.seatLargeBlue')
    if (active) { // if found deactivate
      active.className = 'seatLargeGreen'
    }

    seat.className = "seatLargeBlue";
    snum.value = seat.dataset.snum;
    sclass.value = seat.dataset.sclass;
  } else if (seat.className == "seatLargeBlue") {
    seat.className = "seatLargeGreen";
    snum.value = "";
    sclass.value = ""
  }
}

for (const [i, b] of seats.entries()) {
  b.addEventListener('click', e => select(e.currentTarget))
}
```

```css
.seatLargeBlue button {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.seatLargeGreen button {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.seat_button_large {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<article class="column1">
  <table class="table_seats">
    <tr>
      <td class="seatLargeGreen" colspan="2" data-snum="1" data-sclass="Business">
        <button class="seat_button_large">
          1
        </button>
      </td>
      <td class="aisle" rowspan="3"></td>
      <td class="seatLargeGreen" colspan="2" data-snum="2" data-sclass="Business">
        <button class="seat_button_large">
          2
        </button>
      </td>
      <td class="aisle" rowspan="3"></td>
      <td class="seatLargeGreen" colspan="2" data-snum="18" data-sclass="Economy">
        <button class="seat_button_large">
          18
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</article>
<input id="snum">
<input id="sclass">
```

Comment: thanks, that worked great... one follow up question though, how could I modify this so that when 1 button is blue, the rest are green, ie, there is always only 1 blue button and the other 17 are green?

Comment: @FrankLloydCurwen I added that bit to my answer. You just find the blue one and make it green.

Answer (score 0):

First, indeed you should add a class to them all that will signal they're related.
But let's make a one function for the 18. although that is not necessarily the best solution, it should have the same effect.

Update: referring to the correct element on click by using `Event.target` property

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {

  var element_id = "seatButton" + i;
  var elem = document.getElementById(element_id);

  elem.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    var elem = ev.target;

    if (elem.className == "seatLargeGreen") {
      elem.className = "seatLargeBlue";
    } else if (elem.className == "seatLargeBlue") {
      elem.className = "seatLargeGreen";
    }

    if (elem.className === "seatLargeBlue") {
      document.getElementById('snum').value = 1;
      document.getElementById('sclass').value = "Business";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('snum').value = "";
      document.getElementById('sclass').value = ""
    }

  })

}
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work correctly... the second part works for every button, but the first part, changing the class from green to blue, only changes the last button, regardless of which button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Capture the event on the click that carries the information you need:

```
seatButton1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.textContent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to figure out what your trying to do with your code as it appears to not be a complete example. E.g. num1 and num2 refers to ID's that does not exist in the example HTML. And both functions works on the same 2 ID's.

So its difficult to know if e.g. the code below captures the essence of what you want to do. It makes things a bit more modular/component based as well as putting a bit of "business logic" ties in there, e.g. it seemed like there was a state around if something was Business or not.

Now there is certainly more changes I would add to improve quality as well as separate business values from the presentation, but I don't quite have the time and I also fear that it might just be too much in the light of the code you posted.

```js
// This "Component" holds the logic for what a "Toggle button" is and defines it's behavior in an isolated way.
function ToggleButton(elm, onClick) {
  const button = elm.querySelector('.seat_button_large');
  let isBusiness = false;

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    isBusiness = !isBusiness;
    elm.className = isBusiness ? 'seatLargeBlue' : 'seatLargeGreen';
    onClick(isBusiness);
  });
}

// This "Component" holds the logic for what the "Display of last interaction" and we hook it up to the toggle buttons.
function LastToggleDisplay(elm) {
  const snum = elm.querySelector('#snum');
  const sclass = elm.querySelector('#sclass');
  this.set = (index, isBusiness) => {
    if (isBusiness) {
      snum.value = index;
      sclass.value = "Business";
    } else {
      snum.value = "";
      sclass.value = "";
    }
  }
}

const display = new LastToggleDisplay(document.getElementById("display"));
// The array here is just added so that our "ToggleButtons" are not just dangling, this can be important in cases where "Webapplications" grow in size and especially if we have a SPA as we then may need to clean things up as we change displays and all, so its more a habit than something I think you will really need here. Certain static analysis tools will complain if you just have dangling objects though.
const buttons = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
  buttons.push(new ToggleButton(document.getElementById(`seatButton${i}`), isBusiness => display.set(i, isBusiness)));
}
```

```css
.seatLargeGreen button {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
}

.seatLargeBlue button {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
}
```

```html
<div id="display">
  <input id="snum">
  <input id="sclass">
</div>
<article class="column1">
  <table class="table_seats">
    <tr>
      <td id="seatButton1" class="seatLargeGreen" colspan="2">
        <button class="seat_button_large">1</button>
      </td>
      <td class="aisle" rowspan="3"></td>
      <td id="seatButton2" class="seatLargeGreen" colspan="2">
        <button class="seat_button_large">2</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</article>
```